# How to place elements in columns using bootstrap3 grid

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for making responsive website but when I am giving padding to elements to adjust them in particular column it is breaking in other devices.

I am giving padding in % still it's breaking.

What should I do?

What is the best way to adjust elements within a particular column?

Comment: can you show you html and css???

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the grid elements intact. Add children inside them to add padding.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="element-with-padding"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="element-with-padding"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```